# p5.js library the 'random()' function?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to gain some practice using constructor functions but I'm coming up with an error regarding the random() function:

12: Uncaught ReferenceError: random is not defined
"%cDid you just try to use p5.js's random() function? If so, you may want to move it into your sketch's setup() function.\n\nFor more details, see: github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#why-cant-i-assign-variables-using-p5-functions-and-variables-before-setup"

Can I only use this function in the setup() function? I don't think I've come across that issue before. Is there a solution using similar logic?

```
var circles = function(x,y,d,xSpeed,ySpeed) {
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.d = d;
this.xSpeed = xSpeed;
this.ySpeed = ySpeed;
}

var circle1 = new circles(random(width),random(height), random(30,55),random(3,19),random(3,19));
var circle2 = new circles(random(width),random(height), random(30,55), random(3,19),random(3,19));
var circle3 = new circles(random(width),random(height), random(30,55), random(3,19),random(3,19));
var circle4 = new circles(random(width),random(height), random(30,55), random(3,19),random(3,19));
var circle5 = new circles(random(width),random(height), random(30,55), random(3,19),random(3,19));
var circle6 = new circles(random(width),random(height), random(30,55), random(3,19),random(3,19));


function setup() {
 createCanvas(900,900);

 }

function draw() {

 background(0);
 fill(255,255,0);
 ellipse(circle1.x,circle1.y,circle1.d,circle1.d); 
}

 function moveCircles() {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, technically you can use this function outside the `setup()` function by using on-demand global mode, as the documentation says. But it is recommended to use this function only inside the `setup()` function, if you're not using any other third-party library.

**p5 functions before setup**

```
new p5();  // you need to call this fn first

var circle1 = new circles(random(width),random(height), random(30,55),random(3,19),random(3,19));
var circle2 = new circles(random(width),random(height), random(30,55), random(3,19),random(3,19));
var circle3 = new circles(random(width),random(height), random(30,55), random(3,19),random(3,19));
var circle4 = new circles(random(width),random(height), random(30,55), random(3,19),random(3,19));
var circle5 = new circles(random(width),random(height), random(30,55), random(3,19),random(3,19));
var circle6 = new circles(random(width),random(height), random(30,55), random(3,19),random(3,19));
```

**p5 functions insde setup**

```
var circle1, circle2, circle3, circle4, circle5, circle6;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(900, 900);
    circle1 = new circles(random(width), random(height), random(30, 55), random(3, 19), random(3, 19));
    circle2 = new circles(random(width), random(height), random(30, 55), random(3, 19), random(3, 19));
    circle3 = new circles(random(width), random(height), random(30, 55), random(3, 19), random(3, 19));
    circle4 = new circles(random(width), random(height), random(30, 55), random(3, 19), random(3, 19));
    circle6 = new circles(random(width), random(height), random(30, 55), random(3, 19), random(3, 19));
}
```